# How can I change the background color of a cell by a condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I change the background color of a cell by a condition by a numeric value?

**For example**, when the price is greater than 10, the background is colored red.

I did this but the value remains constant, I want this to apply to all values that are greater than 100, for example.

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}"
        Header="Price">
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="100">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Can you show a sample xaml for this example?

Comment: Please share some code, or elaborate on your question so we can understand what you are asking and help.

Comment: Corentin Pane, Branden, Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use an `IValueConverter` to convert prices into colors and define a `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` to use this converter.**

Define this somewhere in your code:

```cs
public class PriceToBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter {
    // Converts a value into a color.
    // Returns Red if value is greater than 100, else White.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        int price = (int)value;
        if (price > 100) {
            return Brushes.Red;
        } else {
            return Brushes.White;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this converter by adding it to the `Resources` of your `DataGrid` (or of any parent control) and using a `Setter` to style all `DataGridCell` objects.

```xml
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <wpfapp1:PriceToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="PriceToBackgroundColorConverter"></wpfapp1:PriceToBackgroundColorConverter>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Price, Converter={StaticResource PriceToBackgroundColorConverter}}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This will instruct your `DataGridTextColumn` to apply a `Style` to all its `DataGridCell` children, and this `Style` binds the `Background` property of each `DataGridCell` to its `Price` property through the `PriceToBackgroundColorConverter`.

You can change the converter code to perform any kind of logic you want, have several colors for different ranges etc.

You can also define more converters and more `Setter` to change additional properties.